# Playstore App publishing rejected Deceptive Behavior policy: Violation of Deceptive Behavior policy

Tags: android, publish

### My App Description

I have been posting my Free betting tips in my app and showing my betting results in a screenshot too

### My App's privacy policy [Privacy Policy](https://uniq-bets.com/privacy-policy/)

### My App Link from google drive [App link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ds40Ea1TDDLIzDCntYB4CxusbxXQHwTD/view?usp=sharing)

### My Screen Shot of the App

[image: This is my screenshot of the app]

### reason for my app getting rejected in playstore submission

[image]

### My Rejected email

[image]

### Please someone help me understand why my app got rejected in playstore What should I change to release my app

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [questions about the policies of app distribution channels are considered to be off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).